# Make a calculation with jQuery and a CSS property

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make a calculation with a css property but it doesn't return anything.

I think it may be because the css property is returning '200px' rather than simply '200'. Can anyone suggest a work around? Many thanks.

```
windowHeight = $(window).height(); // This works
logoHeight = $('.home h1').css('height'); // This returns '200px'
logoPosition = windowHeight * 0.5 - logoHeight;
```

Comment: The value you request from css is a string containing 'px' you need to replace this via JS yuorself or parse the number.

Comment: Note that there are better ways to center something vertically than javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
windowHeight = $(window).height(); // This works
logoHeight = $('.home h1').css('height'); // This returns '200px'
logoPosition = windowHeight * 0.5 - parseInt(logoHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks very much - this was the most useful just because it helps me understand the issue and how to put other CSS into an integer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert the "200px" string to an integer; using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
windowHeight = $(window).height(); // This works
logoHeight = parseInt($('.home h1').css('height'), 10); // This returns '200px'
logoPosition = windowHeight * 0.5 - logoHeight;
```

Otherwise your sum `windowHeight * 0.5 - logoHeight` is returning `NaN` (not a number).

It is important to *always* specify the radix as the second parameter to `parseInt`, or you'll find things like;

```
parseInt("022") == 18; // true
```

Answer (score 3):

You should just be able to use `height()` on the `<h1>` element:

```
windowHeight = $(window).height(); // This works
logoHeight = $('.home h1').height(); 
logoPosition = windowHeight * 0.5 - logoHeight;
```

Comment: This is better than using `css('height')` because you make better use of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other examples to show you how to use other CSS properties and jQuery methods.
[Check our jQuery style properties](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/style-properties/)

```
var element = $('#element');
var borderLeftWidth = parseInt(element.css('borderLeftWidth'), 10); // css border-left-width
var borderRightWidth = parseInt(element.css('borderRightWidth'), 10); // css border-right-width
var fullWidth = element.outerWidth(false); // includes padding and border but not margins
```